# "import translate" in a way that works with Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, dynamic-loading

I'm trying to make my script cross-Python (Python 2 and 3 compatible),
and to solve an import problem I did this:

`__init__.py` file

```
import sys

if (sys.version_info[0] < 3):
    from core import translate
else:
    from .core import translate
```

Is it the good way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No that's not the best way to import in both Python2 and Python3, if you have to support Python 2.5.0a1 and above.
This is as you can use:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from .core import translate
```

[As documented in the `__future__` module.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html)

Comment: Not sure if the question does belong here but this answer definitly taught me something! Thanks :)

Comment: this will work for any python version >2.5?

Comment: @mou no >=2.5, but you shouldn't be running Python2.5

Comment: You can also use explicit relative imports without `from __future__ import absolute_import`, or import the module by its fully-qualified name with `from whatever.core import translate`. The future statement just turns off implicit relative imports.